# Why doesn't this LINQ Select expression work

Tags: c#, linq, select

I've got a difficult LINQ expression and I can't figure out why it doesn't work.  The syntax error I get is

> The type of arguments for `Enumerable.Select<TSource,
>   TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TResult>)` cannot be
>   inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

The error is on the second `Select` statement, `x.Select`.  I'm trying to grab one element in each List of List from `allFactors` and add them together and keep each of each grouping that was added together in `tempList`.  In other words, I want to keep the individual elements together in `tempList` and know their total in `temp`.

Earlier in the code `allFactors` is filled with values.  How can I specify the types explicitly or do this another way.  I can't understand why it doesn't infer the types either.

```
int temp = 0;
//List<List<int>> allFactors = new List<List<int>>();
List<int> tempList = new List<int>();
allFactors.Select(x => x.Select(y => { temp += y; tempList.Add(y); }));
```

EDIT:
David L's answer does fix the syntax error! Unfortunately with further testing I realize that my code isn't doing what I wanted it to do.  What I really want is to get every permutation whereby each group is made of only one element from a list of lists.  As an example:

```
List<List<int>> oldList = {{1,2},{3,4}};
List<List<int>> newList = {{1,3},{1,4},{2,3},{2,4}};
```

I'm looking for some way to convert `oldList` into `newList`.  The challenge is that I don't know how many nested lists there will be or how many items will be in each list.  Any ideas? Thanks for everyone's thoughts so far.

Comment: What's the type of allFactors?

Comment: Your second `Select` clause doesn't return anything.

Comment: do you want to put only first elements of each list of "allFactors" in "tempList"?

Comment: @DanielBryars, Sorry I didn't clarify.  The commented out variable `allFactors` is from earlier in the code and is the correct data type. However, check out my edit as I have clarified my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type cannot be inferred because you are not returning anything by the inner select. The compiler doesn't have anything to infer for the outer select as a result.

In addition, since you are not using the selected return, you could use `.ForEach()` instead.

```
int temp = 0;
List<List<int>> allFactors = new List<List<int>>();
List<int> tempList = new List<int>();
allFactors.ForEach(x => x.ForEach(y => { temp += y; tempList.Add(y); }));
```

---

If you wanted to stick with `.Select()`, you would need to return the value from the inner select and use `.SelectMany()` for the outer select.

```
int temp = 0;
List<List<int>> allFactors = new List<List<int>>();
List<int> tempList = new List<int>();
List<int> selectedList = allFactors.SelectMany(x => x.Select(y => 
                { 
                    temp += y;    
                    tempList.Add(y); 
                    return y; 
                })).ToList();
```

This would produce a "flattened" `List<int>`, which seems to be in line with your end goal for `tempList`.

Comment: thanks for your clear explanation! Very helpful, I only shallowly know how to use Linq and didn't realize `Select` needed to return something.  I see what you mean now that I've looked at the documentation. Please see the edit as I've clarified the question.

Comment: @michaelto20 Happy to help and thank you for the clarification.  In this case however, because the nature of the question has changed so drastically, it would be better to create a new question.

Comment: good suggestion, if you have any thoughts here is the new post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37791100/creating-a-list-getting-an-element-from-each-nested-list

Answer (score 1):

If you want just flatten the "allFactors" you can go this way:

```
        var tempList = allFactors.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
        var temp = tempList.Sum();
```

If you need only first element of each list, then it will be:

```
        var tempList = allFactors.Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
        var temp = tempList.Sum();
```